# Difference between two types of allocations

Tags: java, performance, bytecode

foo[] example = new foo[4];

**variant 1**

```
example [0] = example [1] = example [2] = example [3] = new foo(5);
```

**variant 2**

```
example [0] = new foo(5);
example [1] = example [0];
example [2] = example [0];
example [3] = example [0];
```

Is there a difference how Java handles both allocations internally? Have the first variant a special name? What is the difference in bytecode?

Comment: The bytecode almost certainly differs, but performance will not differ in any significant way.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thank you

Comment: Is this a programming puzzle a.k.a (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) :-) ? Very interesting question.

Comment: Just an FYI, by changing the question from `int` (a primitive type) to `foo` (an Object type), you're bound to get misleading answers now because people are responding to the wrong thing.

Comment: @Todd I'm searching for an answer for the Object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is all one expression. The assignment expression causes the value to be stored into the array, and then the expression evaluates to the stored value. So it's all one giant expression and the same value is stored at each array position with no intervening reads.

In the second version, it reads from the array each time. If you have multithreaded code and another thread is simultaneously modifying the array, then this could return different results.

For single threaded code, they are effectively identical.

Note: Here's what the first version looks like with parenthesis added to indicate order of evaluation.

```
example [0] = (example [1] = (example [2] = (example [3] = (new foo(5)))));
```

It is equivalent to the following code (note the lack of array reads)

```
foo t = new foo(5);
example[3] = t;
example[2] = t;
example[1] = t;
example[0] = t;
```

P.S. One other difference is that they assign the array elements in opposite order. So if the array has a length less than 4, the first version will throw immediately while the second version will partially fill the array.

Comment: It shouldn't post-optimization, though.

Comment: @Veedrac The JVM may optimize things so that you don't see a race. But it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the bytecodes do differ. Here is the bytecode generated for the first version:

```
   0: iconst_4      
   1: anewarray     #2                  // class com/foo/Allocation$Foo
   4: astore_1      
   5: aload_1       
   6: iconst_0      
   7: aload_1       
   8: iconst_1      
   9: aload_1       
  10: iconst_2      
  11: aload_1       
  12: iconst_3      
  13: new           #2                  // class com/foo/Allocation$Foo
  16: dup           
  17: iconst_5      
  18: invokespecial #3                  // Method com/foo/Allocation$Foo."<init>":(I)V
  21: dup_x2        
  22: aastore       
  23: dup_x2        
  24: aastore       
  25: dup_x2        
  26: aastore       
  27: aastore       
  28: return
```

And here is the bytecode generated for the second one:

```
   0: iconst_4      
   1: anewarray     #2                  // class com/foo/Allocation$Foo
   4: astore_1      
   5: aload_1       
   6: iconst_0      
   7: new           #2                  // class com/foo/Allocation$Foo
  10: dup           
  11: iconst_5      
  12: invokespecial #3                  // Method com/foo/Allocation$Foo."<init>":(I)V
  15: aastore       
  16: aload_1       
  17: iconst_1      
  18: aload_1       
  19: iconst_0      
  20: aaload        
  21: aastore       
  22: aload_1       
  23: iconst_2      
  24: aload_1       
  25: iconst_0      
  26: aaload        
  27: aastore       
  28: aload_1       
  29: iconst_3      
  30: aload_1       
  31: iconst_0      
  32: aaload        
  33: aastore       
  34: return
```

I personally find both versions less readable than

```
Arrays.fill(example, new Foo(5));
```